# SQL query joining multiple tables and getting information thats in one but not the others

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I am having trouble with making a query that joins three different tables and getting information from different ones.

The tables are:

```
TableP
DataP1 (primary key)


TableL
DataL1 (primary key)
DataP1 (foreign key)


TableA
DataA1 (primary key)
DataP1 (foreign key)
Date
```

I need to show the DataP1 values that do not appear in TableL but appear in TableP and TableA, along with the related dates taken from TableA

So far I have something like this:

```
Select TableL.DataP1, TableA.date
from TableP
inner join TableL on TableP.DataP1 = TableL.DataP1
inner join TableA on TableP.DataP1 = TableA.DataP1
```

but this shows just the values that are in TableL and not in TableA and TableP (basically the opposite)

I tried adding things like ...

```
when TableL.DataP1 <> TableA.DataP1
```

... but this didn't seem to help.

If you could offer insight into where I am going wrong, it would be very helpful
Thanks

Comment: You'll want to join on TableL last and use a `left join`: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join against TableL instead of an inner join, then only select rows with null values in the TableL portion of the data:

```
SELECT p.DataP1, a.Date
FROM TableP p
INNER JOIN TableA a ON p.DataP1 = a.DataP1
LEFT JOIN TableL l ON l.DataP1 = p.DataP1
WHERE l.DataL1 IS NULL
```

Inner join requires that both sides of the join (i.e., both tables) have records that match on the join criteria. Left join will always return results for the table on the left side of the join, even if there are no matches on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

To show `DataP1` values that are in `TableP` *and in* `TableA` you use an inner join:

```
SELECT TableP.DataP1
  FROM TableP
  INNER JOIN TableA On TableP.DataP1 = TableA.DataP1
```

To show `DataP1` values that are in `TableP` *and **not** in* `TableL`, do an outer join and look for instances where `TableL.DataP1` is `NULL`:

```
SELECT TableP.DataP1
  FROM TableP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableL ON TableP.DataP1 = TableL.DataP1
  WHERE TableL.DataP1 IS NULL
```

To put it all together (`DataP1` values in `TableP` and in `TableA` and *not* in `TableL`):

```
SELECT TableP.DataP1
  FROM TableP
  INNER JOIN TableA On TableP.DataP1 = TableA.DataP1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableL ON TableP.DataP1 = TableL.DataP1
  WHERE TableL.DataP1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer and made it much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a left join and check for null fields

```
SELECT TableL.DataP1, TableA.date
FROM TableP tp
inner join TableA ta on tp.DataP1 = ta.DataP1
LEFT JOIN TableL tl ON tl.DataP1 = ta.DataP1
WHERE tl.DataP1 IS NULL
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't start my "FROM" clause with the table I want to exclude.  From my understanding of your question:

Data is desired that is found in both TableP and TableA; however, exclude this record if found in TableL.

```
SELECT 
     l.DataP1
   , a.Date

FROM TableP p
   Inner Join TableA a 
   on p.DataP1 = a.DataP1
   Left Join TableL l
   on p.DataP1 = l.DataP1
WHERE
  -- you'll join on TableL and here you exclude it when the data is found there
   l.DataL1 is null
```

The Inner join to table A will assure you only pull records that have data in both P and A.  The Left join to Table L will show you records that both have and don't have data in Table L... in this case, your where clause then excludes records when it is found in Table L.